# Python bool values with conditional statements

Tags: python, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

Why does `bool[False]` evaluates to true but `bool(False)` evaluates to false?

As per python docs:
"*Any object whose value is not undefined or null, including a Boolean object whose value is* false, evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement."

Both tuple and lists are objects then why this ambiguous behavior?

Comment: (False) is not a tuple, (False,) is a tuple

Comment: Btw, the only thing `bool[False]` would evaluate to is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `bool([False])`? A non-empty list will evaluate to `True`, and an empty list evaluates to `False`. The list `[False]` is not empty, so it is `True`.

`bool([])` evaluates to `False`.

`(False)` is not a tuple. You will need to use `(False,)`. `bool((False,))` evaluates to `True` because it is a non-empty sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Learnt something new today!!!